PHP Extends through includes doesn't work with parent in file2 / child in file1
So i was making a basic code and came across this problem.
I first had all my code in one file, afterwards i split the different classes into individual files.
While doing that i was doing that i had a parent class in a different file and wanted to check if it broke anything, and then it told me that the child class doesn't exist.

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Cat' not found in /home/main.php:7 Stack trace: #0 /home/main.php(4): Start->main() #1 {main}   thrown in /home/main.php on line 7

It worked when the child class had it's own file tho, which was confusing to say the least.
So i tried to reproduce the error in a smaller code.
main.php
<?php

include('animal.php');

$start = new Start();
$start->main();

class Start {
    public function main(){
    $cat = new Cat("Luna", 7, "4 kg");
    var_dump($cat);
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal{

}

?>

animal.php
<?php
class Animal {
    public $name;
    public $age;
    public $weight;
}

I tried to see if it might work if i use online GDB or XAMPP but they had the same error.
Whenever animal is still in the main.php or class cat is has it's own file it works fine.
I would really like to know why and how this happens as I'm pretty new to coding and want to understand why this is happening.
There is no reason other than my curiosity.

You use the class Cat in your main() method before the class is defined a couple lines below. It is possible to automatically load a class definition, but starting out you should learn to include or require your files in the correct order so that there are no errors.

@PeterPointer That's not correct - See here. PHP is not executed line-by-line it's get interpreted

Oh right they also use new Start() before the class definition. It's been a while since I used PHP without a class autoloader. @Teramisu I recreated your code without using include files and it indeed doesn't give an error: Start my cat demo. Maybe the include doesn't find your PHP file? Try require instead to error out if the file is missing.

I already tried using require instead of include @Peter Pointer
The thing is it works just fine if i put cat into a seperate class of it's own.
For some reason the extend just doesn't work from the main through include or require

You should look into what @PeterPointer said about autoloading your classes before using them. This will make your life a lot easier. There are also a lot of question about autoloading on SO already if you have problems  implementing this
